# MySQL match against literal string in some columns but not in others

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a query

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tbl_listing AS al
WHERE 
(MATCH(al.title, al.listing_title) AGAINST('search query*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR
MATCH(al.description) AGAINST('search query' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR
MATCH(al.artist_full_name) AGAINST('search query*' IN BOOLEAN MODE));
```

which works OK but I can't seem to work out how to ensure the description search is a literal search.

So if I have

```
search.php?search_query=Abstract+Painting+Philisophical+Spiritual+Barzakh+
```

I would like all records where title, listing_title and artist contain any of the query words and the description ONLY if the phrase is a match in any part of the description.

Thanks

Comment: Your query has fundamental security problems; please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection, and rewrite it accordingly.

Comment: It is a stripped down version of the actual query

Comment: We actually have other injection protection on our WAF but thanks for sharing the link

Comment: I strongly suggest that you not rely on that. It cannot possibly handle all of your use-cases.

Comment: Sorry, the written question only shows a stripped down version (written by hand) of the query and only shows the MATCH for the parts I need the literal search to be performed on.

Comment: We don't just rely on that. We have escape functions too but they are just not shown in the question.

Comment: Firstly -- that's still the wrong approach; it's still safer to use bind variables rather than escaping. Secondly -- the escaping logic will affect how you rewrite the query for your stated requirement, so you shouldn't strip it out of the question.

Comment: Thanks. We are considering the move to PDO however this site is massive and will take a long time so a bit more planning needs to be done first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add double quotes where you want an exact phrase match:

```sql
....
WHERE 
    MATCH(title, listing_title)
        AGAINST('search query' IN BOOLEAN MODE) -- matches if any one word is present in "title" or "listing_title"
OR
    MATCH(description) AGAINST('"search query"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) --  matches the exact phrase only
```

Adapt the logical operators to suit your needs.